# jquery addclass not working with animate.css

Tags: jquery, html, css, animate.css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function() {
    $(".test").addClass("animated shake");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<span class="test">element</span>
```

where do i make mistakes? Thank you from now for your helps...

Answer (score 3):

It because `span` is an inline element so `transform` and other properties will not work...

...so try to add `display:inline-block` to the span

> ***[Read this for more info on inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)***

...Also in your jQuery code use `$(this).addClass("animated shake")` instead of `$(".test").addClass("animated shake")`.

`$(this).addClass("animated shake")`... it will add class to the clicked `.test` element.

`$(".test").addClass("animated shake")`... it will add class to all `.test` element.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("animated shake");
  });
});
```

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<span class="test">element</span>
```